# Ambiguous Exception with calcHist in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I've been getting the following ambiguous error when trying to use `cv2.calcHist()`

```
>>> img
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.])
>>> cv2.calcHist( [img], channels = [0], mask = np.ones(img.size), histSize = [6], ranges = [(0,6)])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
SystemError: error return without exception set
```

The error is so generic that I have absolutely no way of knowing what could be going wrong. You can find the function documented [here](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html).  I am currently running OpenCV v2.3.1 as installed through MacPorts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I find the online documentation a bit sparse for the Python interface.
One resource I find invaluable are the samples (`OpenCV-2.3.x/samples/python2`), in which you can find example use of almost all the functions in the Python interface.

However looking at the documentation:

- the `mask` argument must be 8-bit (`mask.astype('uint8')`)
- the input `img` should be `CV_8U` or `CV_32F` (so `img.astype('uint8')` or `img.astype('float32')`)

And from looking at the `python2` samples (`camshift.py`,`color_histogram.py`):

- the `ranges` argument doesn't need to be a tuple, just a list (although the documentation suggests it should be a list of lists or array of arrays...)

So:

```
cv2.calcHist( [img.astype('float32')],                 # <-- convert to float32
              channels=[0], 
              mask=np.ones(img.size).astype('uint8'),  # <-- convert to uint8
              histSize=[6], 
              ranges=[0,6] )                           # <-- flat list
```

Comment: I didn't realize there were examples!  MacPorts is pretty quiet about what it installs.  In the end, I realized that it would be faster and easier to use `numpy.histogram` instead of OpenCV's solution.

Comment: I had the same issue. The `ranges` argument not being a flat list was a problem for me.